# Mappped buffer read int

Tags: java, buffer, nio

I have 2 simple functions to write a int and read it from mapped file but it seems that one of the functions is wrong.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Random;

public class MemoryMappedFileInJava {

  // file
  File file;
  // channel to connect the file content to buffer
  FileChannel channel;
  // buffer
  MappedByteBuffer buffer;
  // buffer max size in bytes
  final int BUFFER_MAX = 32;

  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  MemoryMappedFileInJava() {

    file = new File("file.txt");
    //create a channel to write and read
    try {
      channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // map the file content to buffer
    try {
      buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, BUFFER_MAX);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  // read the value from buffer
  int readInt() {
    int number=0;
    int c = buffer.getInt();
    buffer.position(0);
    while (c != '\0')
      number += c;
    return number;
  }

  // send the message to buffer
  void writeInt(int number) {

    buffer.position(0);
    buffer.putInt(number);
    buffer.putChar('\0');
  }

  // close the channel 
  void closeChannel() {
    try {
      channel.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  //lets make some tests with random numbers
  static void run() {
    Random r = new Random();
    MemoryMappedFileInJava communication = new MemoryMappedFileInJava();

    int number = r.nextInt(5) + 1;
    communication.writeInt(number);
    String prefix = "the given number from buffer is --> ";

    System.out.print(prefix + communication.readInt());
  }

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    run();
  }
}
```

the full code that im using to run this code can also be compiled and run from here:
http://tpcg.io/5hOPVh1Q

The output print is always giving 0 and i cant find where is the problem if is in write function or read function.

Comment: I doubt this code is giving you anything, since it cannot run due to the major syntax and compilation errors. Please post the actual code you are compiling and running.

Comment: @MarcoR. added the link with full code that im using to run this code:http://tpcg.io/5hOPVh1Q

Comment: Your question must be whole here in SO. Members will not hunt down the details of your question across the internet; so edit your question and post the source here. Any non-essential details of the question can be linked after the essential ones are found here.

Comment: @MarcoR. you are right , i have updated the code in my question post.

Comment: Get rid of the parts that deal with the NUL character. They are not required, and some of them don't make any sense. You don't even need the methods actually: just call `getInt()` and `putInt()` directly. I don't see why you're calKing `buffer.position(0)` either. Is there really only one number? at the beginning of the file? NB These are binary numbers and should not be written to a file named .txt.

Comment: @user207421 i kind of agree with you, but even without all  all those conditions and just call the putInt() and getInt() it will not going to work

Comment: @user207421 at debug the buffer is getting the following line :java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=32 cap=32] , its seems that the buffer converts the int value to bye and big endian , so without calling buffer.position(0) it will move to position 4 , maybe the reason that getInt() was giving 0. The ansewer bellow fixed this problem. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the reason for the `number` variable or the `while` loop in the `readInt` method. If you just want to read an `int` from the beginning of the `buffer`, then changing your `readInt` method to the following works just fine:

```
    int readInt() {
        buffer.position(0);
        return buffer.getInt();
    }
```